# How can I sum price on all page in the laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreach, pagination, laravel-5.6

My query like this :

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')->paginate(10);
```

My view blade like this :

```
@php($total = 0)
@foreach ($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $order->number }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->price }}</td>
        ....
    </tr>
    @php($total += $order->price)
@endforeach
...
Total : {!! $total !!}
{{ $orders->links() }}
```

From the script, I just get total price in one page

How can I get total price in the all page?

Comment: so you need to know how to do a sql query that `sum`s a column?

Comment: @lagbox Yes I know that. But this is already set in pagination. So it can not sum all

Comment: is there some unsaid restriction that is stopping you from querying the database to sum a column of a table?

Comment: @lagbox Actually my query is too compleks. There is `where`, `group by` etc. The above query is just an example. So I need to use only 1 query

Comment: you want sum all price in your database price column ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel view composers:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers

Basically, create a provider or put in the AppServiceProvider.

```
public function boot() {
    \View::composer('*', function($view) {
        $view->with('sumOrderPrice', \DB::table('orders')->sum('price'));
    });
}
```

or

```
\View::share('sumOrderPrice', \DB::table('orders')->sum('price'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest you to not break MVC pattern, all logic must be done in your controllers, let do it by the controller itself or a service, but prepare all your data before pass it to the view, so prepare a $sum variable doing a foreach in your controller, if don't want to do it at least don't write logic in your view, and use the method "sum" on your collection instance, take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sum, so your code will become:

```
//in your controller
$orders = DB::table('orders')->paginate(10);


//in your view
@foreach ($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $order->number }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->price }}</td>
        ....
    </tr>
@endforeach
...
Total : {{ $orders->getCollection()->sum('price') }}
{{ $orders->links() }}
```